# jquery replace mouse cursor with animated image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm replace the cursor to 2 images with small distance by this code:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#firstImage").css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
        $("#secondImage").css({
            left: e.pageY + 50,
            top: e.pageY
        });
});
```

Now I want to add animation -

so that the images move right and left together (the first image right and the second - left, and after that the first left and the second right), and it need to be all the time.

```
setInterval(function () {
        $("#first").animate({
            left: "-=100px"
        }, 2000);
        $("#second").animate({
            left: "+=100px"
        }, 2000);
        $("#first").animate({
            left: "+=100px"
        }, 2000);
        $("#second").animate({
            left: "-=100px"
        }, 2000);
    }, 4000);
```

The problem -

if I give to it "left" css properties - it's no longer follows the mouse movement, but returns all time to where it was when I set the animation.

Comment: Although you have done well to include your attempted code so far, unfortunately it is very unclear what you are asking? Can you try to describe your requirement a bit more clearly please

Comment: jsbin or jsfiddle perhaps?

Comment: why dont you create a sprite and change the background-position?

Comment: Create a container div and set it position to absolute, place the images inside it with position relative.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto, can you add code? I don't understand how to do container, but it sounds well.

Comment: there you go! http://jsbin.com/timuz/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/timuz/1/edit)

#### HTML

```
<div id="mousemove">
  <img id="first" src="http://xxx.png">
  <img id="second" src="http://xxx.png">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#mousemove {
  position: absolute
}
#first, #second {
  position: relative
}
```

#### JS

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e){
  $("#mousemove").css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});

setInterval(function () {
  $("#first").animate({
    left: "-=100px"
  }, 2000);
  $("#second").animate({
    left: "+=100px"
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You made the impossible possible! I could not believe that there is a solution!!! Thanks a lot!